# ListView Popup key functionality

Tags: wpf, listview, popup, listviewitem

I have implemented a listview that appears as a popup list. Now I would like to add key functionalities to it, like if whenever up arrow is pressed in a text box it should select an item in my list view and if pressing of KEY_UP/DOWN is continued it should continue changing its index respectively.

This is the `EditMessageTextBox` and associated `EditMessageTagPopup` [image]

This is the XAML code used:

```
<Grid x:Name="EditGrid"
      Grid.Row="1"
      Visibility="{Binding EditMessageControlVisibility}"
      FocusManager.IsFocusScope="False"
      VerticalAlignment="Center"
      Grid.Column="1"
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Border x:Name="EditMessageBorder"
          Grid.Row="0"
          BorderThickness="1"
          CornerRadius="1"
          Margin="0,10,0,0"
          BorderBrush="Gray">
    <Grid>
      <TextBlock FontSize="16"
                 Margin="10,0,0,3"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Text="Edit message"
                 Foreground="{StaticResource brushWatermarkForeground}"
                 Visibility="{Binding ElementName=EditMessageTextBox, Path=Text.IsEmpty, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
      <TextBox Name="EditMessageTextBox"
               Text="{Binding MessageToEdit, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
               BorderBrush="Transparent"
               BorderThickness="0"
               Foreground="Black"
               FontSize="16"
               Margin="8,1,1,1"
               VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
               MinHeight="35"
               ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
               TextWrapping="Wrap"
               AcceptsReturn="False"
               KeyUp="OnEditMessage_KeyUp"
               SpellCheck.IsEnabled="true" />
    </Grid>
  </Border>
  <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
              Margin="0,10"
              Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button Background="Transparent"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
            Padding="5,2,5,3"
            Foreground="Black"
            BorderBrush="Gray"
            BorderThickness="0.8"
            Width="100"
            materialDesign:ShadowAssist.ShadowDepth="Depth0"
            Click="EditMessageCancelButton_Clicked">Cancel</Button>
    <Button Name="EditMessageButton"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
            Padding="5,2,5,3"
            Background="#007a5a"
            Foreground="White"
            BorderBrush="#007a5a"
            Margin="15,0,0,0"
            materialDesign:ShadowAssist.ShadowDepth="Depth0"
            BorderThickness="0.8"
            IsEnabled="True"
            Width="140"
            Content="Save Changes"
            Click="EditMessageSaveButton_Clicked" />
  </StackPanel>    

  <Popup x:Name="EditMessageTagPopup"
         AllowsTransparency="True"
         IsOpen="{Binding IsOpenTagPopUp}"
         StaysOpen="False"
         Placement="Top"
         PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=EditMessageTextBox}">
    <Border materialDesign:ShadowAssist.ShadowDepth="Depth5"
            CornerRadius="5"
            Background="White"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="0.8"
            MaxHeight="200">
      <ListView x:Name="EditTaggedUsers"
                Focusable="True"
                IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource UserListForTag}}"
                SelectionChanged="EditMessageTagList_SelectionChanged">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
          <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
              <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                  <Border Name="_Border"
                          Padding="8">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                  </Border>
                  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                             Value="True">
                      <Setter TargetName="_Border"
                              Property="Background"
                              Value="#FF3BD38E" />
                      <Setter Property="Foreground"
                              Value="White" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                             Value="True">
                      <Setter TargetName="_Border"
                              Property="Background"
                              Value="#FF205B4B" />
                      <Setter Property="Foreground"
                              Value="White" />
                    </Trigger>
                  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
              </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
          </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="-15,0,0,0"
                  Width="500">
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <Rectangle Grid.Column="0"
                         RadiusY="5"
                         RadiusX="5"
                         Height="20"
                         Width="20">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                  <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ProfileImage}"
                              Stretch="UniformToFill" />
                </Rectangle.Fill>
              </Rectangle>
              <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                         Text="{Binding FullName}"
                         Margin="-10,0,0,0" />
            </Grid>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
    </Border>
  </Popup>
</Grid>
```

and here is code behind:

```
 ApplicationContext.StoredEditingMessage = (String)ApplicationContext.EditMessageText;
                var messageData = ((TextBox)sender).DataContext as ChatsModel;
                var EditMessagePopup = FindEditMessagePopup(MessageList);
                Border EditEessageBorder = EditMessagePopup.Child as Border;
                ListView EditMessageTagList = EditEessageBorder.Child as ListView;

                Dispatcher?.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    if (_contactsViewModel.GroupedChatByDate
                        .Find(x => messageData != null && x.MessageGuid == messageData.MessageGuid)
                        .IsOpenTagPopUp == false) return;
                    var index = _contactsViewModel.UsersListForTag.IndexOf(_contactsViewModel.UsersListForTag.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Selected == true));


                    switch (e.Key)
                    {
                        case Key.Up:
                            if (EditMessageTagList.SelectedIndex > 0)
                            {
                                EditMessageTagList.SelectedIndex -= 1;
                                EditMessageTagList.ScrollIntoView(EditMessageTagList.Items[EditMessageTagList.SelectedIndex]);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                EditMessageTagList.SelectedIndex = _contactsViewModel.UsersListForTag.Count - 1;
                                EditMessageTagList.ScrollIntoView(EditMessageTagList.Items[EditMessageTagList.SelectedIndex]);
                            }
                            break;
                        case Key.Down:
                            if (EditMessageTagList.SelectedIndex + 1 == _contactsViewModel.UsersListForTag.Count)
                            {
                                EditMessageTagList.SelectedIndex = 0;
                                _contactsViewModel.UsersListForTag[index].Selected = true;
                                EditMessageTagList.ScrollIntoView(EditMessageTagList.Items[EditMessageTagList.SelectedIndex]);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                EditMessageTagList.SelectedIndex += 1;
                                _contactsViewModel.UsersListForTag[index].Selected = true;
                                EditMessageTagList.ScrollIntoView(EditMessageTagList.Items[EditMessageTagList.SelectedIndex]);
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                    _contactsViewModel.UsersListForTag.ForEach(x => x.Selected = false);
                    if (index != -1)
                    {
                        _contactsViewModel.UsersListForTag[index].Selected = true;
                    }
                });
```

I have tried adding an item in scroll into view() instead of selected index yet no update

when there is a perfect selection made this function is invoked from code behind

```
private void EditMessageTagList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var messageModel = ((ListView)sender).DataContext as ChatsModel;

            if (((ListView)sender).SelectedItem is UserModel selectedUserForTag)
            {
               // _contactsViewModel.GroupedChatByDate.Find(x => messageModel != null && x.MessageGuid == messageModel.MessageGuid) .IsOpenTagPopUp = false;
                string SelectedTag = (selectedUserForTag.Id == ApplicationContext.CurrentLoggedInUserGuid) ? $"{selectedUserForTag.UserName.Replace("(you) ", "")} " : $"{selectedUserForTag.UserName} ";
                _contactsViewModel.GroupedChatByDate.Find
                    (x => messageModel != null && x.MessageGuid == messageModel.MessageGuid)
                .MessageToEdit = "@" + SelectedTag;
            }

            // ((ListView) sender).SelectedItem = null;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            LoggingManager.Error(exception);
        }
    }
```

[Here is screen recording regarding issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15Chu.gif)

and

[Here is working functionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImHvS.gif)

Comment: What you describe is the default behavior of the `ListView`. After you gave focus to the `ListView` (e.g. by clickingon an item) you can navigate through its items by using the up/down keys.

Comment: if I clicked on an item of the list view it gets added into below textbox and popup listview is closed

Comment: Then why do you close it? It will close by itself once the  `Popup` lost focus.

Comment: once clicked an item in that popup list the item gets added into below text box as shown, so I need to implement key functionality when listview popup is opened when "@" is typed

simply when @ is typed I need to circulate within popup listview using keyboard only

Comment: As I said before. All you need to do is give focus to the `ListView`. Now wehen pressing an arrow key you automatically navigate through the items. You could use the `Popup.Opened` event to move focus to the `ListView` by calling `this.EditTaggedUsers.Focus()` from inside the handler.

Comment: Your links are not public and require a Youtube account with special permission to watch the content.

Comment: yeah Updated my links to public youtube

Comment: I checked your link. Now I understand you. Your example is incomplete as it misses the `TextBox` to show the selected item. Let me update my answer.

Comment: Consider to convert the video to a gif and attach it to your question. This is more convenient then leaving this page to follow external links.

Comment: thanks for this tip @BionicCode, I have updated gifs in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that after each navigation to the next item of the `ListView` you want to set focus to the selection `TextBox` which binds to the `SelectedItem`. Otherwise navigating the items of a `ListView` with the help of the arrow keys is already the default behavior of the `ListView`.

The simplest solution is to capture the keyboard input using `UIElement.InputBinding` on the selection `TextBox` (which enables to handle the keys in the view model) and then

1. Select the next/previous item
2. Scroll the SelectedItem into view
3. Move the focus to the selection `TextBox`
4. Move the caret of the selection `TextBox` to the end

**DataItem.cs**

```
class DataItem
{
  public string FullName { get; set; }

  public DataItem(string fullName) => this FullName = fullName;
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ObservableCollection<DataItem> DataItems { get; set; }
  public ICommand SelectNextCommand => new AsyncRelayCommand(SelectNextItem);
  public ICommand SelectPreviousCommand => new AsyncRelayCommand(SelectPreviousItem);  

  private bool IsSelectedItemChangeInternal { get; set; }

  private DataItem selectedDataItem;
  public DataItem SelectedDataItem 
  {
    get => this.selectedDataItem; 
    set
    {
      this.selectedDataItem = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();

      // Do not filter the list when the selected item was set by the user
      // e.g. by using arrow keys
      if (!this.IsSelectedItemChangeInternal)
      {
        UpdateSearchFilter();
      }
    }
  }         

  private string filterKey;
  public string FilterKey
  {
    get => this.filterKey; 
    set
    {
      this.filterKey = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();

      // Only apply filters when the FilterKey was changed by the user
      // e.g. by editing the edit TextBox that binds to this property
      if (!this.IsSelectedItemChangeInternal)
      {
        ApplySearchFilter();
      }
    }        
  }         

  public ViewModel()
  {
    this.DataItems = new ObservableCollection<DataItems>();
    for (var index = 0; index < 100; index++)
    {
      this.DataItems.Add(new DataItem("name " + index.ToString());
    }
  }      

  private void ApplySearchFilter()
  {
    ICollectionView collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.Games);
    this.IsSelectedItemChangeInternal = true;

    collectionView.Filter = item => 
      string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.FilterKey) || (item as DetailItem).FullName.StartsWith(this.FilterKey);

    // pre-select the first match
    collectionView.MoveCurrentToFirst();

    this.IsSelectedItemChangeInternal = false;
  }  

  private void UpdateSearchFilter()
  {        
    this.IsSelectedItemChangeInternal = true;
    this.FilterKey = this.SelectedDataItem.FullName;
    this.IsSelectedItemChangeInternal = false;
  }

  private void SelectNextItem()
  {
    ICollectionView collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.DataItems);
    collectionView.MoveCurrentToNext();

    // Loop
    if (collectionView.IsCurrentAfterLast)
    {
      collectionView.MoveCurrentToFirst();
    }
  }

  private void SelectPreviousItem()
  {
    ICollectionView collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.DataItems);
    collectionView.MoveCurrentToPrevious();

    // Loop
    if (collectionView.IsCurrentBeforeFirst)
    {
      collectionView.MoveCurrentToLast();
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private void AdjustFocus_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  var listView = sender as ListView;
  listView.ScrollIntoView(listView.SelectedItem);

  Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
  {
    Keyboard.Focus(this.EditMessageTextBox);
    this.EditMessageTextBox.CaretIndex = this.EditMessageTextBox.Text.Length;
  });
}

private void AdjustFocus_OnOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.EditTaggedUsers.Focus();
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  </Window.DataContex>

  <Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="EditMessageTextBox"
             Text="{Binding FilterKey}">
      <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Down"
                    Command="{Binding SelectNextCommand}" />
        <KeyBinding Key="Up"
                    Command="{Binding SelectPreviousCommand}" />
      </TextBox.InputBindings>
    </TextBox>

    <Popup IsOpen="True"
           Opened="AdjustFocus_OnOpened"
           StaysOpen="False"
           Placement="Top"
           PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=EditMessageTextBox}">
      <ListView IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                Height="400"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDataItem}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding DataItems}"
                SelectionChanged="AdjustFocus_OnSelectionChanged">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DataItem}">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding FullName}" />
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
    </Popup>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

### Remarks

As the navigation is done using the `CollectionView` of the `ItemsSource` the `ListView.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` property must be set to `true`. Otherwise the navigation of the `CollectionView` won't effect the view.

Comment: thanks!! already tried it but once focus is sent to listview we cant alter textbox text and it works only once I require it to circulate

Comment: I updated my answer. The key is to use the attached properties of the [`KeyboardNavigation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigation?view=netframework-4.8) class. This way you can enable navigation loop and exclude specific elements inside a container from being a navigation target (tab stop).

Comment: Sorry for saying this!!
I am new to WPF can you please be more precise or can you give me an example like u did above for FOCUS() ??

Comment: I did. Just check my XAML code. You must notice the two attached properties `KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation` and `KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation`. Add them and run the example together with the `Popup.Opened` event.

Comment: ok now I get what you are saying!! but my text box control is in another grid when "@" is typed in that particular textbox this popup list is opened and then key functions should circulate.

the one u are saying works when both textbox and popup list are under the same parent

Comment: Well, you have no information about this `TextBox`. You are free to move it anywhere you like. Just add the name and the `InputBindings` to it. It should still work as the `TextBox`is referenced by name. I hope you are not complaining as your question is really bad as you are hiding almost all details. You are only showing `Popup` and ask how to loop through the `ListView`using arrow keys.

Comment: You never mentioned a `TextBox` and related behaviour. Anyway, this will work as long you name the `TextBox` "EditTextBox" or adjust all code parts to match your vision naming.

Comment: Sorry For not mentioning a text box, actually I forgot about it I have updated my question regarding XAML layout of this issue any suggestions

Comment: I added`IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` to popup list view and here is how it works fine but issue there is that scrolling into the selected item is not happening at all

Comment: I updated my answer. I fixed some copy&paste errors and added the search functionality. Now typing into the edit text box will filter the list. To make the selected item scroll into view you have to bind the `SelectedItem` property. I highly recommend to copy my complete example code. It is a working example and should get you started. You only have to adjust the XAML by adding the appropriate namespaces. Then gradually replace controls and modify the example step by step. Good luck.

Comment: I've updated the `DataItem` and the `ViewModel` classes to generate a number of default items.